# Regular expression \w+(?=@)

Tags: regex

I am currently using `\w+(?=@)` expression to extract username only from AD credentials.
However this causes issues when the username has a "dot".

Can anyone help me modify this expression, so I can fetch the entire username which looks like

> mary.jane

Answer (score 1):

For that you can simply do:

```
[\w.]+(?=@)
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/sF4bY8

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to allow more than only word characters (`\w`). You can do this by using a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). You can define one by using square brackets:

```
[\w.]+
```

This would match at least one out of the characters from inside the square brackets. Inside of a character class, there are different characters special, so you don't need to escape the `.`, like you have to outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^.+(?=@)
```

this means `from beginning of line till you find @`

Comment: Should probably be the non-greedy `.+?`.

Comment: Yes I agree. But in an email address, there can be only one `@` so that won't make a difference. Not sure if AD supports multiple `@` in username.

Comment: Ah, I must've missed that it was an email address, but then they can contain "@" in the local-part. [Regex really isn't the right tool for the job.](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: Yes I agree. If a simple string search can be performed, RegEx is an overkill. It has big performance implications. But since the question was originally about regex rather than performance, I didn't want to discuss that in my answer. :)